# Radio buttons using jquery to change a select menu

Tags: jquery

Hello i'm trying to have my raido button choice select a drop down menu when i select sports I want different sports to show up and when I select cars I want different brand of car brands to show up but when I click on either one nothing shows up so how can i get my radio button choice to show the drop down menu thanks.
Here is a link for the code http://jsfiddle.net/saber2356/fv8LLu9w/

```
<script>
$(function(){
    //$("[name=select]").change(function(){
        $('input[type=radio][id=radio1]').change(function() {
            $("#list").toggle($("[name=select]").index(this)===0);
            $("#list2").toggle($("[name=select]").index(this)===1);
        }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

And the Page

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">Interest?</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Radio1" id="Radio1" class="Radio1" value="sports"> Sports </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Radio1" id="Radio1" class="Radio1" value="cars"> Cars </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4" id='choose'>Choose One</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <select class="form-control" div id="list" name='Cars' style='display:none'>
                    <option>Ford</option>
                    <option>Gm</option>
                    <option>Toyota </option>
                    <option>Other</option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control" name='Sports' div id="list2" style='display:none'>
                    <option>Baseball</option>
                    <option>BasketBall</option>
                    <option>Football </option>
                    <option>Hockey</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: Correct indentation can make your life way easier.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fv8LLu9w/1/

SCRIPT:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function (e) {
       var whichOne = $(e.currentTarget).val();
       $('select').hide();
       $('select[name=' + whichOne + ']').show();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4">Interest?</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Radio1" id="Radio1" class="Radio1" value="Sports"> Sports </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Radio1" id="Radio1" class="Radio1" value="Cars"> Cars </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="control-label col-xs-4" id='choose'>Choose One</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <select class="form-control" div id="list" name='Cars' style='display:none'>
                    <option>Ford</option>
                    <option>Gm</option>
                    <option>Toyota </option>
                    <option>Other</option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control" name='Sports' div id="list2" style='display:none'>
                    <option>Baseball</option>
                    <option>BasketBall</option>
                    <option>Football </option>
                    <option>Hockey</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block">
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```